# Windows (7 & Vista) laptop monitor does not come back after closing lid

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, display

I'm experiencing an issue with Windows Vista (and now Windows 7) with my laptop. When I close the laptop lid the monitor goes blank but will not come back on after I re-open the laptop. The screen stays blank and nothing that I do will get it to come back. The laptop is an HP DV9000 series.

Has anyone else ran into this issue? One of the solutions I've seen online is to go into the device manager and replace the lid driver with something nonsensical (the website suggested pointing the driver at the sound recorder). This does solve the problem by disabling the lid but doesn't really resolve the root issue.

I'm asking if anyone has any method I can use to debug what's going on. How do I tell if it is an operating system issue vs. a malfunction within the lid itself. I'd actually like the lid to function as it's meant to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also want to see if there is a BIOS update for your notebook.  Things like what you describe can sometimes be caused by ACPI (i.e. power management) oddities that can be (and often are) fixed in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i did a clean install of windows ecently.

All i had to do was call task manager alt+ctrl+del and the screen came back.

The problem dissapeared after i did another clean install of windos 7

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I put my laptop in sleep mode and close the lid.

Typically I open it, which boots it with a blank screen, then sleep it again (with the lid open). If I then boot it again it will give me my login screen.

Possibly you could try to use your function key (Fn) or Windows logo + P to make it switch screens to get to your desktop.

Off course these are rather "hacky" ways and are merely based on trial and error. Hopefully I can find something more conclusive like changing settings, do you need the screen to go blank when you close the lid?

Comment: I would like it to go blank for power/heat saving purposes. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 defaults to  going to sleep when closing the lid and the hibernating after a set amount of time. Pressing the power button is the only way to wake it up (press it once, don't hold it down). Under the power settings you can change Windows to only turn off the screen when closing the lid.

Comment: @Luminose: Unfortunately I've changed the power settings to not sleep on lid close and only turn off monitor. When I re-open the laptop I can tap keys etc. and hear the default beeping in the background indicating I'm hitting something, just no picture. Thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

Many times the cause of not waking from sleep is the fault of either a video driver or chipset driver. I'd look and see if the manufacturers of those parts have newer drivers out (don't bother looking at HP's site, they usually have older drivers).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Vista (seems to work correctly with Windows 7).  With Vista, I had to turn off wifi first, then hibernation would work correctly.  When I'd forget to turn off wifi it was hit or miss (almost always a miss).

Comment: @Giovanni Galbo: So you had to run without wifi if you wanted to use the lid? (or had to turn off wifi every time before you closed the laptop?). Oddly enough I recall the lid functionality working fine until I installed either the MS Office Suite or Visual Studio 2008. I suppose I could try uninstalling these and trying again. Thanks for the reply !

Comment: I think my issue is a little different, now that I re-read the question.  On Vista, I would have to turn off wifi before hibernating.  If I didn't it would not go to sleep properly (it would be in some sort of zombie state.... fan still on, hard-drive not spinning, monitor off [similar to what you're experiencing].

It works as designed on Windows 7 (Interestingly enough, by looking at the wifi light I think Windows 7 just shuts off the wifi before sleeping and then turns it back on when waking up)

Answer (score 0):

Is the lid button getting stuck? Usually it's just a little pin that gets pressed in when you close it; try pressing it yourself and see if it pops out freely. As long as the Power Options are all set to "just turn off monitor", I'd lean toward a hardware issue before an OS problem.

Comment: @Andrew: Nope I thought that at first but it's not stuck. I'm just leaving the lid up for now and turning on the power saving mode for the monitor. Thanks for the reply !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have added RAM which works though is not certified for the laptop from HP, it will cause this issue.  Take out all add-on RAM and try putting the system to sleep and waking back up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Vista on Acer Aspire. I Solved it by enabling hibernate file properly. The solution is real simple but there are details. I think you need to solve the hibernate problem first, then sleep problem. Check this out: http://annoyances-resolved.blogspot.com/2009/09/vista-sleep-problem-laptop-not-waking.html

Answer (score 0):

Ideas for resolving not coming out of sleep:

1. Look in your BIOS for the suspend ACPI options and try to switch modes among "S1 and S3", "S3" etc.
2. Ensure "Allow this device to wake computer" is checked in in "Device Manager/$device$/ Properties/Power Management", where $device$ stands for keyboard and mouse.
3. [Turn off Hybrid sleep](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/turn-off-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-7/), see explanation [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-hybrid-sleep-mode/) (for vista, but is the same)
4. The hibernation file is sometimes disabled by disk cleaning, to restore do in cmd run as administrator "powercfg -h on".

Note: Any of the above manipulation that doesn't help should be undone.

You can use the following command to troubleshoot sleep problems and return a detailed report:

> powercfg -ENERGY

[image]