# Monitor is not coming out of standby

Tags: windows, display, standby

Sometimes when my computer wakes from standby the screen stays blank, and no matter how much wiggling of the mouse or hitting keys I do it won't 'wake up' the monitor.  My only option is to do a cold restart, which loses any unsaved info etc.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep problems occur again and again on this forum.
This is a retake of my answer for thread [23820](https://superuser.com/questions/23820/windows-7-vista-laptop-monitor-does-not-come-back-after-closing-lid).

Things to try :

1. Look in your BIOS for the suspend ACPI options and try to switch modes among "S1 and S3", "S1", "S3" etc.
2. Ensure "Allow this device to wake computer" is checked in in "Device Manager/$device$/ Properties/Power Management", where $device$ stands for keyboard and mouse.

Note: Any of the above manipulation that doesn't help should be undone.
Item 1 was the one that worked the last time a similar question was asked.

Answer (score 3):

Some BIOSes have an option along the lines of "Refresh VGA BIOS on standby wakeup" or something like that (can't look right now but it was something like that) which did the trick for me. Though that was in the ancient times of Windows 2000 here.

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue with one of my monitors similar to this, but in my case it's when I first boot up my PC. In my case it's fixed by unplugging and then reconnecting the DVI cable.

When it first started happening I swapped the monitors and cables around trying various combinations, but it always seemed to be the the same monitor that experienced the problem.

It doesn't happen often enough for me to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work in Windows, but when I had this problem in Ubuntu, I could fix it without by rebooting by going in and out of sleep mode. Not a fix, but a better workaround than rebooting.